# Bourne shell: how to add prefix string to stderr message?

Tags: shell, sh, io-redirection

I'm running a script on a Bourne shell, eg not bash (actually the sh from BusyBox 1.23.2).

As asked & answered in [this question on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/882019/linux-shell-how-to-add-prefix-string-to-stderr-message), I'd like to "catch" error messages issued by commands within my script, and preappend a string to have them stand out in the log file.
However contrary to the answer provided in the linked question, I cannot use process substitution because the shell is not bash.

I'm redirecting all outputs to a log file:

```
#exec 3>&1 4>&2 >>$LOGFILE 2> >(sed 's/^/ *** ERROR:  /' >&1)
#  -->  -sh: syntax error: unexpected redirection
exec 3>&1 4>&2 >>$LOGFILE 2>&1
```

precision: As shown by the use of the exec statement, I'd like to apply that prefix on all outputs of the shell, eg not on the output of a sub-shell.

Answer (score 2):

The following works under busybox:

```
$ { find /var/cache/ldconfig 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | sed 's/^/error: /' ; } >> /tmp/log 2>&1
```

Now for the explanation:

- `find /var/cache/ldconfig` produces message on stdout and stderr
- `3>&1 1>&2 2>&3` permutes stdout and stderr (using a temporary file descriptor, 3)
- `| sed 's/^/error: /'` performs the insertion on the stdout stream (former stderr)
- `{ cmd ; } >> /tmp/log 2>&1` makes it possible to group then redirect stdout and stderr correctly (grouping everything in a kind of anonymous function), appending the error and out stream to `/tmp/log`

Comment: How would you adapt this to use the bare `exec` statement, which redirects output for the shell itself, not a specific command?

Comment: @chepner: what about `{ exec 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3  | sed 's/^/error: /' ; } >> /tmp/log 2>&1` ? I don't 100% understand what you're trying to do with the exec statement

Comment: neat trick exchanging outputs, however this will only work for the sub-shell. I think @chepner question is: how can we do that for the shell, not a sub-shell? The problem is to append the string on every output then, not just the one resulting of the sub-shell...